# X axis of histogram out of order in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Despite the dtype of the column being an int64, the x axis is still out of order. I even tried sorting the dataframe column in ascending order. But it didn't work.

```
csv_path ="https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/snakes_count_100.csv"
df3 = pd.read_csv(csv_path, usecols=[' "Game Length"'])
df3 = df3[1:51]
#df3.head()
ax = plt.axes()
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, horizontalalignment='right')
plt.hist(df3)
plt.legend()
plt.title('Game of snakes')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.xlabel('Game Length')
```

https://ibb.co/mWaBHf

Comment: _the x axis is till out of order_  — exactly, what do you mean please?

Comment: https://ibb.co/mWaBHf

Comment: Isn't `plt.hist(df3.values)` what you want?

Comment: Yes! Thanks, I just missed that by accident

Comment: Or, `df3.hist()` ...

Comment: You values are strings. Convert them to a numerical datatype before plotting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `hist` method of the `DataFrame` class itself.

With some re-ordering of the commands, you can stick to the rest of your code:

```
csv_path ="https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/snakes_count_100.csv"
df3 = pd.read_csv(csv_path, usecols=[' "Game Length"'])
df3 = df3[1:51]
df3.hist()
ax = plt.axes()
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, horizontalalignment='right')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Game of snakes')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.xlabel('Game Length')
```